Do UUID variants matter for parsing UUIDs?
I wondered if you have seen any UUID libraries in any programming language that would refuse to parse UUIDs with an invalid variant/version. The reason, why I assume there has to be something is:
In RFC 4122, under section 4.1.1 (Variant), the last sencenye says "Interoperability, in any form, with variants other than the one
defined here is not guaranteed, and is not likely to be an issue in
practice."
And 4.1.3: "The following table lists the currently-defined versions for this
UUID variant."
So let's say when I develop on a platform which doesn't have any UUID generator, and I have to generate (random) UUIDs myself: Is it okay to just randomly generate all 16 bytes? I could end up with a variant reserved for future purposes and a version 15. But does anybody care?
I've looked into some UUID parsers but have not seen any code that checks for anything except length and format.

It's a bit hard to answer whether any library in any language would refuse to parse them. But it sounds like what you really want is just an unstructured 128 bits that you format and parse as hex, so why bother with a UUID at all? Also, note that if you randomly generated all the bits, you could well end up with a standard-variant UUID that thinks it's Version 1, for example — so you probably want to at least guard against that, at which point why not just handle the variant.

(You could also end up with a standard UUID that has a non-standard version, and it wouldn't shock me if that caused errors in some code; there are probably some switch (version)s out there that assume a value of 1-5)

Well I do have to interact with a .net API which uses UUIDs. But the (G/U)UID parser there doesn't care, so no problem in my case. But maybe it could have bin, if I wasn't using .net.
